# How to deploy dotcms war file into the existing tomcat server?

Tags: dotcms

I downloaded dotcms1.9.3 from http://dotcms.com/downloads/, how can i deploy it into tomcat 6, i do know that i have to create or modify some files like specify the mysql (not POSTGRESQ )database connection string to make the system work, can you go into detail about it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Ethan, copy your war file into tomcat 6 webapp root directory. like  `tomcat6/webapp/youwarfile.war`. and configure your virtual directory with the same name of your war file withour .war extension `yourwarfile` in tomcat from config folder. For Reference check this link [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/).